# ValueError: The view **** didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using Django forms to handle user input for some point on my Django app. but it keeps showing this error whenever the user tries to submit the form.

```
ValueError: The view *my view name goes here*  didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead
```

Here's the code:

**Forms.py**

```py
class sendBreachForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Form for sending messages to users.
    """
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = forms.FileField()
    cords = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"type":"hidden"}
    ))
```

**views.py**

```py
@login_required
def web_app(request):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('/ar/system/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = sendBreachForm(request.POST)
            print("AAAAAAAAa in a post request")
            if form.is_valid():
                print("AAAAAAAAa form is valid")
                text = form.cleaned_data['text']
                image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                cords = form.cleaned_data['cords']
                try:
                    new_breach = Breach.object.create(text=text,image=image)
                    add_form_cords_to_breach(request,new_breach,cords)   
                    print("AAAAAAAA added breach")
                    return render(request,"web_app.html",context)         
                except :
                    print("AAAAAAAA error ")
                    return render(request,"web_app.html",context)   
                    # raise Http404('wrong data')
                    
        else:
            form = sendBreachForm()
            context = {}
            context['form']=form
            context['all_elements'] = WaterElement.objects.all()
            current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
            the_domain = current_site.domain
            context['domain'] = the_domain
            all_layers = MapLayers.objects.all()
            context['all_layers']=all_layers
            return render(request,"web_app.html",context)
```

**HTML**

```html
                  <form method ='post'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.text}}
                    <label for="text">وصف المعاينة</label>
                    {{form.image}}
                    <label for="image">صورة المعاينة</label>
                    {{form.cords}}
                      <input type="submit" value = "إرسال المعاينة">
                </form>
```

Comment: `if form.is_valid():` - okay, what if the form *isn't* valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes complete sense, the view should return some response in all the conditions, currently you have both `if` and `else` condition for everything, except `if form.is_valid()` so also maintain in that.

```py
@login_required
def web_app(request):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('/ar/system/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = sendBreachForm(request.POST)
            print("AAAAAAAAa in a post request")
            if form.is_valid():
                print("AAAAAAAAa form is valid")
                text = form.cleaned_data['text']
                image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                cords = form.cleaned_data['cords']
                try:
                    new_breach = Breach.object.create(text=text,image=image)
                    add_form_cords_to_breach(request,new_breach,cords)   
                    print("AAAAAAAA added breach")
                    return render(request,"web_app.html",context)         
                except:
                    print("AAAAAAAA error ")
                    return render(request,"web_app.html",context)   
                    # raise Http404('wrong data')
            else:
                print("form is not valid")
  
                messages.error(request,"form is not valid, kindly enter correct details")
                return redirect("some_error_page")
                    
        else:
            form = sendBreachForm()
            context = {}
            context['form']=form
            context['all_elements'] = WaterElement.objects.all()
            current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
            the_domain = current_site.domain
            context['domain'] = the_domain
            all_layers = MapLayers.objects.all()
            context['all_layers']=all_layers
            return render(request,"web_app.html",context)
```

Comment: `print("form is not valid")` isn't solving the issue, you still need to `return` something…

Comment: @deceze Yes you're right, but it's just an example, the OP can return error messages, and redirect to some error page.